# Как сделать разные вкладки по переключению?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать разные вкладки на одной странице, т.е. [image: Пример]
Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку 2, содержимое блока 1 скрывалось, показывалось содержимое второго блока. (без обновления страниц и перехода на другие вкладки)

Comment: Чтоб не изобретать велосипед, попробуй bootstrap https://bootsnipp.com/tags/tabs

Comment: на радио кнопках сделать можно, без js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Tabs {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onTabListItemClick = this.onTabListItemClick.bind(this);
    this.unsetActiveTab = this.unsetActiveTab.bind(this);

    this.tabList = this.node.querySelector(".tab__list");
    this.tabContentItems = this.node.querySelectorAll(".tab__content-item");

    this.tabList.addEventListener("click", this.onTabListItemClick, false);
  }

  onTabListItemClick(event) {
    const item = event.target.closest(".tab__list-item");
    const index = [...this.tabList.children].indexOf(item);

    if (!item) return;

    this.unsetActiveTab();
    this.setActiveTab(item, index);
  }

  unsetActiveTab() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".tab__list-item")].forEach(node => node.classList.remove("tab__list-item_selected"));

    [...document.querySelectorAll(".tab__content-item")].forEach(node => node.classList.remove("tab__content-item_selected"));
  }

  setActiveTab(item, index) {
    item.classList.add("tab__list-item_selected");

    this.tabContentItems[index].classList.add("tab__content-item_selected");
  }
}

new Tabs(document.querySelector(".tab"));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.tab {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

.tab__list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.tab__list-item {
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab__list-item_selected {
  background: #fff;
}

.tab__content {
  padding: 50px;
}

.tab__content-item {
  display: none;
}

.tab__content-item_selected {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab">
    <ul class="tab__list">
      <li class="tab__list-item tab__list-item_selected">Item 1</li>
      <li class="tab__list-item">Item 2</li>
      <li class="tab__list-item">Item 3</li>
      <li class="tab__list-item">Item 4</li>
      <li class="tab__list-item">Item 5</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab__content">
      <div class="tab__content-item tab__content-item_selected">
        <h1>Title #1</h1>
        <p>Paragraph #1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab__content-item">
        <h1>Title #2</h1>
        <p>Paragraph #2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab__content-item">
        <h1>Title #3</h1>
        <p>Paragraph #3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab__content-item">
        <h1>Title #4</h1>
        <p>Paragraph #4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab__content-item">
        <h1>Title #5</h1>
        <p>Paragraph #5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Странно что никто не плюсанул, классно сделал. Лови плюс.

Comment: JavaScript (Node)?

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов, ванильный js